# Ubuntu root only is limited to 10 GiB on a ~3 TB drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD30EZRX-19D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  650MB   649MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      650MB   10,7GB  10,0GB  ext4
 3      10,7GB  18,8GB  8193MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      18,8GB  3001GB  2982GB  ext4
```

I used [this](http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-15-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware/) tutorial for installing Ubuntu.

My `/home` folder properties show that it has 2.7TB of free space but package installations fail due to insufficient space.

Is this supposed to be happening? As far as I understand I should be able to use the 2.7TB in my /home directory. If not, how can I use it?

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  9,3M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       9,1G  6,9G  1,7G  81% /
tmpfs           7,8G  4,3M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       618M  3,4M  615M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4       2,7T   89G  2,5T   4% /home
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1,6G   88K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

**EDIT:** Installing anything from steam doesn’t seem to be failing due to space issues, but anything from the software center does.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. It's hard to figure out what you're looking for. If you want a troubleshooting tip, take a look at how space is being used on that partition.

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited the question.

Comment: Rather than `parted`, please provide the output of `df -h`.

Comment: Updated the main post seeing as I can't figure out how code formatting works in the  comments

Comment: Looks like you made an error when installing Ubuntu. Your root (`/`) partition is only 10 GiB.

Comment: Should I reinstall? If so can you point me in the right direction regarding partition sizes and flags etc...?

Comment: You mean you just installed Ubuntu and this is the result? Please make clear what the situation is. It's quite important to know if this is a new installation or one that is used for months or years. That could mean a lot more work. When asking questions - please make sure to give us all information that we need to answer your question. What have you tried, what worked, what not, etc. Did you use let the installer do the partitioning, or did you try to set the partions yourself? Without these information you waste our time and effort, and your own time as well.

Comment: @JustasD I removed your additions to the title. Please keep speculation inside the question body. Your `/home` partition is *not* limited to 100 GiB, why would it be? `df` (as well as your file manager) clearly show there’s plenty of space available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to repartition and use manual partitioning when installing ubuntu.

Since your disk is big and using only linux as the operating system, it is better to use LVM partitions. They have the convenience of extending, shrinking, deleting , adding partitions much easier. If using LVM, efi boot partition shouldn't be a lvm partition, reserve sda1 for it and sda2+ for lvm.

Also, keeping media / personal files in another partition as opposed to huge home is recommended.

- efi boot = 500MB
- root = 30GB
- home = 100GB.
- swap = minimum of ram size.
- media partitions.

With LVM, you can always create smaller sized logical volumes at first and extend them as necessary. Shinking volumes is also possible but is risky.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/

[Extending a logical volume](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/extendlv.html)

Comment: Why not have `/home` in a separate partition? It’s also where Steam games reside, IIRC.

Comment: With `/home` on seperate partition, Incase one wants to reinstall os reusing the older unformatted `/home` partition, the older user configuration files get reused, retaining any bad behaviour. True with root user and user with same name in both installations.

Comment: Certainly. But in most cases, this is the desired behavior. Who’d want to lose their browser bookmarks? (Re)moving the configuration files is a trivial task, should the need arise. Backing up the whole home directory, however, can be quite tedious. The root home directory is at `/root`.

Comment: Agreed. Edited my answer to reflect seperate `/home`